# How to force fix unexpected newline, expecting { after if clause error in golang and vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

is it possible to automatically correct the error "unexpected newline, expecting { after if clause" when I automatically write the bracket after if/else on a separate line? I keep doing it because I'm used to this from other languages.

go fmt doesn't fix it, it just reports it to me
other tool from google I don't have found
prettier is not available for golang formatting
various extensions from vscode, even if explicitly set, do not fix this either

it's really annoying when I write a file where there are a lot of such errors and then I have to fix it manually.